# Isolation issue using Chromium NW.js

Tags: chromium, nwjs

I'm using Chromium NW.js as a web browser integrated into a desktop application.

Essentially, this enables me to incorporate a web application within a desktop application. I have been using it for many years without any problems.

However, I recently encountered an issue. When a link is loaded into this application, I receive an error.

Upon analyzing it with the inspector, I observed the following warnings/errors in the console:

```
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'browsing-topics'.
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecosnized feature: 'interest-cohort'.

The page requested origin isolation, but could not be isolated since the origin https://example.com had previously been seen with no isolation. Update your headers to uniformly isolate all pages on the origin.

Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'browsing-topics'
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognazed feature: 'interest-cohort'.
The page requested origin isolation, but could not be isolated since the origin 'YYYY' had previously been seen with no isolation. Update your headers to uniformly isolate all pages on the origin.
```

Answer (score 0):

Permissions Policies are related to the **ALLOW** attribute of an iframe.

They include permission for the loaded site to access things like...

> microphone, camera, geolocation, midi, encrypted-media, and vr
> (virtual reality)

In an iframe you'd set it like this...

```
<iframe src="https://trusted.com/" allow="geolocation; https://trusted.com/">
```

NB: With the above, other sites that later load in this same iframe won't have access to geolocation.

If the attribute is not present and the site requests access to one or more of the above, you can set it on the fly with...

```
iframe_ID.setAttribute('allow','camera; microphone; https://trusted.com/'); 

iframe_ID.contentDocument.location.reload();
```

You get the drift...